# С# задача по удалению кратных

Tags: c#

Всем привет,не подскажите как сделать на языке С# так,чтобы метод принимал текст в которым бы удалялись все кратные рядом стоящие символы,оставив по одному.Пример:ПППОООГГГООООДДДААА >>> ПОГОДА.

Comment: Использовать цикл и StringBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой алгоритм

```
private static string RemoveDupl(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return text;
    var sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
    sb.Append(text[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < text.Length; i++)
        if (text[i] != text[i - 1]) sb.Append(text[i]);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Как использовать

```
Console.WriteLine(RemoveDupl("ПППОООГГГООООДДДААА"));
```

вывод

```
ПОГОДА
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь.